# Loading Images on-demand (or; disable loading of hidden images)

Tags: jquery, html, css, image, deferred-loading

I have a slider-like widget which is basically, a div of sub-divs containing some page content (together with images).

Initially, all sub-divs are hidden except the main one.

My problem is that all web browser seem to load (request) all images in the content, whether they're hidden or not.

In my case specifically, it will end up loading some 350 images at one go. This is a **lot**, especially when considering images are at the very least **200kb**. In fact, the network log specifies that the total website size is in the range of **6mb to 7mb**.

All these images hinder page load, especially because they are expected to load before other page elements (eg; buttons etc).

What is the solution to my problem? Things I tried already:

- loading each sub-div as ajax. This is not possible, the page content must be there at all time.
- hiding the images themselves (in the hope that the web browser does not load them). This failed, the browser still loaded images with CSS `display:none;`.
- **Possible solution:** intentionally break the markup (server-side) so that the browser does not load the images, eg; writing `<img alt="abc.jpg" src="about:blank"/>`, then when tab switches, I would fix the markup correctly with jQuery. I haven't tried this yet, is it advisable?

Comment: I also use the possible solution but instead of using alt attribute I use data-src attribute, this way you can still use the alt attribute. Works very well, but ofcourse if someone has disabled javascript it will fail the page.

Comment: @jeffreydev They wouldn't be able to see the page anyway. Does `data-src` work with older browsers?

Comment: ive tested it in IE6 and above, firefox, google chrome and safari

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, as I hinted in the question, a possible solution can be achieved by the following trick:

```
<?php
    // server-side content
    echo str_replace(' src=', ' data-dly="" src="blank.gif" data-src="', $html);
?>

// client-side script
function showPage(id){
    hidePages();

    var page = jQuery('#page'+id);

    page.find('img[data-dly="1"]').each(function(){
        jQuery(this).attr('src',jQuery(this).attr('data-src'));
    }).removeAttr('data-dly').removeAttr('data-src');

    page.fadeIn();
}
```

NB: Thanks to **@jeffreydev** for the help as well.